# How to work work with layouts in react-router elegantly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have two components `FirstLayout` and `SecondLayout` that require `Header` component for displaying the completed page.

At this moment I have come to this decision, that renders `Header` component on both pages and doesn't re-render it when I switch from `/first` to `/second` or from `/second` to `/first` paths

```
function App() {
    return (
        <Route exact path={'/(first|second)'} component={Header} />

        <Route exact path={'/first'} component={FirstLayout} />
        <Route exact path={'/second'} component={SecondLayout} />
        <Route exact path={'/third'} component={ThirdLayout} />
    )
}
```

But if I use the method below, where `FirstLayout` and `ThirdLayout` components already contain `Header` component, `Header` component re-renders each time when I switch from `/first` to `/second` or from `/second` to `/first` paths

```
function App() {
    return (
        <Route exact path={'/fisrt'} component={FirstLayout} /> // FirstLayout already contains Header component
        <Route exact path={'/second'} component={SecondLayout} /> // SecondLayout already contains Header component
        <Route exact path={'/third'} component={ThirdLayout} />
    )
}
```

So, my goal is to achieve some elegant approach in working with layouts and routes. Is there a way to make React understand that Header component should not be re-rendered in the second way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it's encouraged to use multiple Route components for different places in the UI. So your first solution seems correct.

From [react router training](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/sidebar):

> ```
>         // You can render a <Route> in as many places
>         // as you want in your app. It will render along
>         // with any other <Route>s that also match the URL.
>         // So, a sidebar or breadcrumbs or anything else
>         // that requires you to render multiple things
>         // in multiple places at the same URL is nothing
>         // more than multiple <Route>s.
> ```